# Buttons, JTextFields and JComboBox's are unclickable

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

The program consists of a tabbed view with a few `JTextField`'s and `JButton`s in the first two and 2 `JTable`s and `JButton` in the third.  The buttons work fine in the first two tabs, but on the third it is un-clickable. I tried changing the button to something else like a `JComboBox` or `JTextField` but those are uneditable and unclickable also. Setting the `setEnabled()` and `setEditable()` functions to true doesn't seem to work. I have no idea what's going on.

The only thing i have done different from normal is this piece of code to forcefully repaint the tab when I click on a cell in the table. But even when this hasn't been called i still cant

```
ContentIWantToRepaint.this.paintImmediately(ContentIWantToRepaint.this.getVisibleRect());
```

Some other information about the layout:
The contents of the tab are held in a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout`

- `JTextField`
- Table Header
- Table Contents
- `JTextField`
- Table Header
- Table Contents
- Button

Any suggestions?

checkOutPanel.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class checkOutPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTable userTable;
    private JTable bookTable;
    private JScrollPane scrollUserTable, scrollBookTable;
    private JLabel userLabel, bookLabel;
    private DefaultTableModel userTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){return false;}
    };
    private DefaultTableModel bookTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){return false;}
    };
    private int selectedUser, selectedBook;
    private JComboBox date_month, date_day, date_year;

    public checkOutPanel(){

        JPanel mainGrid = new JPanel();//panel that will hold all stuff in tab
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();//panel for holding buttons

        mainGrid.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=0; c.gridy=0; //first row first column
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;//align left
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        //1 row, 2 columns, 15 horizontal padding, 0 vertical padding
        //buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,15,0));

        //labels to describe what the user has to do
        userLabel = new JLabel("User :");
        bookLabel = new JLabel("Book :");
        JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel("Date :");
        JPanel datePanel = new JPanel();

        bookTable = new JTable(bookTableModel);
        bookTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        userTable = new JTable(userTableModel);
        userTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(500, 120);

        scrollBookTable = new JScrollPane(bookTable); 
        scrollBookTable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
        scrollBookTable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
        scrollBookTable.setMaximumSize(d);
        scrollBookTable.setMinimumSize(d);
        scrollBookTable.setPreferredSize(d);

        scrollUserTable = new JScrollPane(userTable); 
        scrollUserTable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
        scrollUserTable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
        scrollUserTable.setMaximumSize(d);
        scrollUserTable.setMinimumSize(d);
        scrollUserTable.setPreferredSize(d);

        updateTables();

        //String[] month = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};       

        //Vector<Integer> days = new Vector<Integer>();
        //for (int i=1 ; i<=31 ; i++) { days.add(i); }

        //Vector<Integer> years = new Vector<Integer>();
        //for (int i=2012 ; i>=1900 ; i--) { years.add(i); }

        //date_month = new JComboBox(days);
        JButton testButton = new JButton("WORK!!!!!!!");
        //date_day = new JTextField(6);
        //date_year = new JTextField(6);

        //datePanel.add(dateLabel);
        //datePanel.add(date_month);
        //datePanel.add(date_day);
        //datePanel.add(date_year);



        mainGrid.add(userLabel, c);                     c.gridy++;
        mainGrid.add(userTable.getTableHeader(), c);    c.gridy++;
        mainGrid.add(scrollUserTable, c);               c.gridy++;
        c.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0);//put some padding between users and books
        mainGrid.add(bookLabel, c);                     c.gridy++;
        c.insets= new Insets(0,0,0,0);//back to no padding
        mainGrid.add(bookTable.getTableHeader(), c);    c.gridy++;
        mainGrid.add(scrollBookTable, c);               c.gridy++;
        c.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0);//put some padding between books and date

        mainGrid.add(testButton, c);                        c.gridy++;





        this.add(mainGrid);//add contents to tab


        userTable.addMouseListener(new mouseListener());
        bookTable.addMouseListener(new mouseListener());

    }

    public class mouseListener implements MouseListener{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==userTable){
                selectedUser=userTable.getSelectedRow();
                userLabel.setText("User :  "+ (selectedUser!=-1 ? selectedUser : ""));

                //don't know why i should need to use this, but it makes it work
                checkOutPanel.this.paintImmediately(checkOutPanel.this.getVisibleRect());


            }else if(e.getSource()==bookTable){
                selectedBook = bookTable.getSelectedRow();
                System.out.println("Date Month : "+date_month.getSelectedItem().toString());
                bookLabel.setText("Book :  "+ (selectedBook!=-1 ? selectedBook : ""));

                //don't know why i should need to use this, but it makes it work
                checkOutPanel.this.paintImmediately(checkOutPanel.this.getVisibleRect());


            }
        }
    }





    private void updateTables(){
        bookTableModel.setDataVector(fillBookData(SystemStart.getDbName()), fillBookColNames());
        userTableModel.setDataVector(fillUserData(SystemStart.getDbName()), fillUserColNames());
    }




    private Vector<String> fillUserColNames(){
        Vector<String> colNames = new Vector<String>();
        colNames.add("ID");
        colNames.add("First");
        colNames.add("Last");
        colNames.add("Phone");
        colNames.add("Email");
        colNames.add("Address");
        colNames.add("City");
        colNames.add("State");
        colNames.add("Zip");        
        return colNames;
    }
    private Vector<String> fillBookColNames(){
        Vector<String> colNames = new Vector<String>();
        colNames.add("Title");
        colNames.add("Format");
        colNames.add("Author");
        colNames.add("ISBN");
        colNames.add("Year Pub.");
        colNames.add("Publisher");
        colNames.add("Call #");
        colNames.add("Copy #");     
        return colNames;    
    }
    private Vector<Vector<String>> fillUserData(String dbName){
        Vector<Vector<String>> v = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        Vector<String> u;
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            u = new Vector<String>(9);
            u.add(""+i);
            u.add("First");
            u.add("Last");
            u.add("Phone");
            u.add("Email");
            u.add("Address");
            u.add("City");
            u.add("State");
            u.add("Zip");
            v.add(u);
        }
        return v;
    }

    private Vector<Vector<String>> fillBookData(String dbName) {
        Vector<Vector<String>> v = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        Vector<String> b;
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){//only include books that arent check out
            b = new Vector<String>(8);
            b.add("Title "+i);
            b.add("Format");
            b.add("Author");
            b.add("ISBN");
            b.add("Year Pub.");
            b.add("Publisher");
            b.add("Call #");
            b.add("Copy #");
            v.add(b);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Use this file to see how it doesn't work:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SystemStart{
    private static String dbName = "dbnamehere.db";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //new TabbedFrame("Libary System");
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("WORK!");
        jf.add(new checkOutPanel());
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static String getDbName(){return dbName;}

}
```

Comment: Could you post some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Are you saying that the `JButton`, `JTextField` and `JComboBox` are contained in a `JTable` ? In that case this is perfectly normal behavior. See the [editor-renderer section in the JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more info

Comment: @Robin - The buttons are outside of the table (The table will contain data from a database, currently it has dummy data)

Comment: @DanielCastro - code added in above post

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @kleopatra - I think i did pretty well naming my variables. But if you need me to explain something, just let me know.

Comment: you did look up _java naming conventions_ in your favourite search engine, didn't you?

Comment: yes. http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: and now compare your class names with what the paragraph _Classes_ in that article :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding to the panel a label, then the table's header and then the scrollpane which contains the table (...and the table header). Remove the two lines where you're adding to `mainGrid` the table headers (you should just add the scrollpanes):

```
    mainGrid.add(userTable.getTableHeader(), c);    c.gridy++;
    mainGrid.add(bookTable.getTableHeader(), c);    c.gridy++;
```

Your button will work now.

Comment: thank you VERY much. Does java automatically add headers above the scroll pane if you initialize the scroll pane with a table?

Comment: Yes, "The scroll pane automatically places the table header at the top of the viewport" (from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), section "Adding a Table to a Container").